# std::thread.join() deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I don't understand why this simple snippet has a dead lock:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
class Test {
public:

    Test() : mExit( false )
    {
        mThread = thread( bind( &Test::func, this ) );
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        if ( mThread.joinable() )
        {
            mExit = true;
            mThread.join();
        }
    }

private:
    void func() 
    {
        while ( !mExit )
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

private:
    atomic< bool > mExit;
    thread mThread;
};

typedef unique_ptr< Test > TestPtr;
TestPtr gTest;

int main()
{
    gTest = TestPtr( new Test );
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit** 
I typed wrong the contstructor set mExit = true

**Edit 2** 
I'm using msvc2012 with v110_xp toolset.

**Edit 3** 
The issue disappear if I explicity call gTest.release() inside main

Comment: I typed wrong, sorry. The issue remain.

Comment: Hmm.  This probably doesn't get better until you use the atomic properly.  And use a debugger to find out what the thread is doing.  Considerable odds that it is off in the weeds, blocking on some OS call instead of burning 100% core checking that exit condition over and over again.

Comment: do you have the same issue if gTest is defined inside main?

Comment: You shouldn't access `mExit` unguarded among different threads. Use a mutex or another syncronization mechanism to protect access to `mExit`.

Comment: @BalogPal no I've not

Comment: @g-makulik - `mExit` is atomic, so no additional synchronization is needed.

Comment: I think that this is a issue with msvc 2012 implementation. Seems the global object aren't destroyed correctly. In effect if I explicit call the destructor of Test the deadlock disappear

Comment: I remember seeing a simar issue with global objects and thread lifetimes here just the other day.  Of course, now I can't find it.  The just was that global object destruction and threads don't play well together and you should ensure all threads are joined when `main()` exits.

Comment: @Chad Perhaps you were referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915233/stdthreadjoin-hangs-if-called-after-main-exits-when-using-vs2012-rc)?

Comment: Is it msvc implementation issue, or the standard say to don't destroy thread outside main func?

Comment: @Chad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093164/why-does-this-c-static-singleton-never-stop

Comment: @pramateek - yes!  This one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915233/stdthreadjoin-hangs-if-called-after-main-exits-when-using-vs2012-rc

Comment: @elvis.dukaj It is a [bug in VS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747145)

Comment: another msvc bug... ok thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have just had this issue, so I post the real answer for others.

In visual studio at least, there is an "exit lock", that is locked when a thread enters the exit code (ie. after `main()` for the main thread, and after `f()` for `std::thread(f)`).

As your Test class is only destructed after `main()` completes, the "exit lock" is locked. Only then you set `mExit = true;` and the other thread is allowed to complete. This other thread then waits to obtain the "exit lock" which is already taken by the main thread, while the main thread waits in `mThread.join();` resulting in the deadlock.

So yes, you need to join all your threads before the main thread has completed.

Comment: So, what is the solution for this case? How to avoid the deadlock of this "exit lock"?

Comment: Don't join threads after `main()` has returned. In particular, if a class joins a thread in its destructor, never make an instance of this class as a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

To me the code looks okay, if its okay with local dut bad with global I'd suspect class related to deinit sequence. The join happens deeply in exit, and implementation might have eliminated some structures already. It should not be the case, but possible.

In any case I always avoid starting thread before main, and leaving any reaching end of main. I consider that only asking for trouble. If you can rearrange it to force join at little erlier point the whole problem might evaporate.

Also you should probably use atomic_flag over atomic.

Comment: Have I some benefits using atomic_flag over atomic<bool> or atomic_bool? I've to investigate better atomics.

Comment: atomic_flag is a sure genuine atomic thing, the most basic element. Other types are allowed to be implemented with internal mutex. IMO unlikely, but why take the chance.

Comment: @BalogPal Because `atomic_flag` is a royal pain to use? ;)

Comment: @ComicSansMS: well, that's indeed a valid motivation. (For such simple cases the difference should not be big.)

Answer (score 0):

Changing code from

gTest = TestPtr( new Test );

to

auto gTest = std::make_unique();

eliminate the problem.

the problem as point above with global object.