# c++ meyers singleton containing std::thread can't join

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, singleton, destructor

i have a problem with the scott meyers singleton. my singleton contains a thread which shall get joined in the singleton destructor, but the join() never returns.

When i join the thread before application exit everything works fine. am i missing something? following my code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& get_instance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        run = false;
        if (t.joinable()) 
            t.join();   
    }

private:
    Singleton() { t = std::thread{ &Singleton::f, this }; }
    ~Singleton()
    {
        std::cout << "dtor start" << std::endl;
        stop();
        std::cout << "dtor end" << std::endl; // <-- never gets called. programm freezes here
    }

    void f()
    {
        while (run)
        {
            // do work ...
            std::cout << "i do some work..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
    }

    std::atomic<bool> run = true;
    std::thread t;  
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto& s = Singleton::get_instance();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    s.stop(); // <-- works fine

    return 0;
}
```

So as i mentioned: with the call to s.stop(); it works fine but without it "freezes".

Is there a way to prevent the call to stop() ?

Comment: It *could* be a kind of reverse static initialization fiasco, where some important part of the runtime library have cleaned up before the `Singleton` instance is destructed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Interesting idea, just wondering what would be the needed global state here? It appears `t` needs to be destructed after `instance`, isn't it? Just iostreams?

Comment: I [cannot reporduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4f8dba9ddb11fe7) cc @Jarod42 linked fixed.

Comment: The output in the destructor may indeed be a problem. If it's *the* problem I don't know. The "deinitialization" order is implementation-specified and can differ between different versions of the same implementation (compiler/runtime library), what will work (or not work) for you will not be the same as for others.

Comment: i tried 32 & 64 bit and debug and release version and get always the freeze. i am using visual studio 2013 community update 4

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg okay i didn't know that this is implementation-dependent. good to know

Comment: if i dont use iostreams it changes nothing by the way

Comment: Works with g++ 4.8.4 (after minor adjustments)

Comment: Just wondering if this is a quirk due to the used compiler: what happens if you declare the member vars before the constructor (which declares the instance var)?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier if i put the thread and the atomic bool objects as first elements to the class declaration i still get the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this C++ static singleton never stop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17093164/why-does-this-c-static-singleton-never-stop)